# How to store assets and manage visibility in blockchain?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, hyperledger-fabric

I want to build a private blockchain where I can store agreements between enterprises. So basically a agreement will have 2 companies and one third-party which monitors it. What I want is in the blockchain only these 2 companies can see the agreement and the third-party can be changed. So if the third-party is changed then the previous party shouldn't be able to see it anymore.

I have used Quorum and Hyperledger 1.0 but none of them provide these sort of visibility options. How can I achieve this in Quorum or Hyperledger 1.0 or in any other platform.

Comment: Are you wanting to use the monitor just to keep watch on the viability of the network? It's a bit confusing when you say that only the 2 companies can see the transaction but if the third party is changed then the previous (the previous third party?) shouldn't be able to see it. If only the 2 companies could see the agreement then what is the third party seeing/not seeing?

Comment: @ChrisSharp It's just an example. Think it of an asset whose visibility can be configured. May be someone nodes can see it and after sometime we can change the list of nodes seeing it.

Answer (score 0):

Proof-of-Authority consensus can be used for authorizing accounts to create transactions and allow other unauthorized nodes to just sync with the chain. Below is the link for implementing the same in Ethereum:
https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/use-puppet-configure-clique-poa-private-blockchain-ajay-singh

Comment: Please provide the content of the link. Without it your answer is not vary helpfull.